# Accidentally created a Git repository in my home folder: How to remove the repository

Tags: git

I accidentally created a Git repository in my home folder. I was wondering what's the best way to remove the repository and it never happening again.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init

Comment: This the mistake i was doing i was not moving to the project dirctory  "If you have a project directory that is currently not under version control and you want to start controlling it with Git, you **first need to go to that project’s directory**.
If you’ve never done this, it looks a little different depending on which system you’re running:”

Excerpt From
Pro Git
Scott Chacon
This material may be protected by copyright."

Comment: Not a big mistake. If you've run `git init` in a directory where subdirectory `.git/` already exists — nothing happens, nothing to fix. If you've run `git init` in a directory where `.git/` doesn't exist — also not a major problem; just do `rm -rf .git` and go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

happened to me as well, type this in the same directory. just make sure you make a new folder next time before `git init`

```
rm -rf .git
```